# Cannot log in to my Debian Wheezy 7 system

Tags: permissions, x11, login, tmp

I have a Debian Wheezy 7 installation. When I turn it on it boots to the log in screen normally. However when I type in my username/password and try to login the screen briefly turns off for about one second and returns to the log in screen. I cannot log in.

I have made no changes to the system other than an owner/permissions change I made to the "/tmp" folder. If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated! Please help.

Comment: "I have made no changes to the system other than an owner/permissions change I made to the "/tmp" folder." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a graphical session requires the creation of files in the `/tmp` directory. If your user no longer has write permission to that directory, graphical logins will fail.

To see that this is the issue, switch to a virtual terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and log in normally. If the changed permissions on `/tmp` are the reason, your log in should succeed.

To remedy the situation, log in from the virtual terminal as root and issue the command:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

This should return the permissions to the default case and allow you to log in normally (to switch back to graphical screen after switching to the VT, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

This often happens if you extract an archive in the `/tmp` directory as the root user.

Comment: Thank you very much Joseph R. I did as you said and I'm back in business!! Hope this post helps someone else having the same issue.

Comment: @BorgesDiaz Glad I could help. For future reference, what helped me diagnose this problem before is looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. It contains the X server log so errors having to do with starting your graphical session usually end up there.